# Possibility to debug from .net code into SQL Server stored procedure code?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, debugging

Is there any possibility to directly dive into SQL Server stored procedures from .net code?
So when debugging step by step in .net, I'd like to step into a called stored procedure.

I know how to debug them individually, but I'd like to join these debug sessions in order to gain some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always found this a little tricky, but it is possible.

First you have to enable T-SQL debugging in the IDE for the project/solution, then you have to set up the database connection as part of the project/solution.

Actually stepping into a stored procedure appears to be troublesome, but if you open the stored procedure code and explicitly set a breakpoint in there, it will hit the breakpoint.

Comment: I'm not sure. It's been a while since I've done it. 
I know that you have to have the connection set up as part of the solution.

Comment: how do you set up the connection to be part of the solution? when I put a breakpoint on the stored procedure, it says No symbols were loaded.

Comment: There are some detailed instructions here:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/debugging-stored-procedures-in-visual-studio-2005

Comment: This is also helpful (for an outdated version of VS, but still accurate): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316549